# Can anyone else recall this book as I do? I have forgotten the title

Tags: story-identification, novel, childrens-novel, medieval

I am looking for a children's book about a girl called Matilda de Chetwynd who gets brought forward to our times (1970's) when the book was written.  The main character (who is rather naughty) goes back to medieval England but returns a reformed character.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You'd think a book with such an unusually named character would be easy to ID.